# How to get full category path from a keyword in Tridion

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

Can any one help me to get full category path from a given keyword. I am giving one example as below,

Example:

Category 1----> Keyword 1 -----> Keyword 11,

say from metadata i got the value "Keyword 11", but i need whole path i.e. /Category 1/ Keyword 1/Keyword 11.

Can anyone help me how to achieve this in Template Building Block using c#.

Comment: Please consider committing to Tridion Area51 proposal to get a dedicated Q&A site for SDL Tridion at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=eo63snjNlUWNn9xqeeO2NA2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below code should help you to get the path.

```cs
bool isRecursive = false;
KeywordField kwdField = (KeywordField)metaFields["kwdField"];
Keyword curKwd = new Keyword(kwdField.Value.Id, engine.GetSession());
string kwdPath = curKwd.Title;
while (!isRecursive) {
  if (curKwd.ParentKeywords.Count > 0){
     foreach (Keyword kwd in curKwd.ParentKeywords) {
        kwdPath = kwd.Title + "/" + kwdPath;
     }
     curKwd = curKwd.ParentKeywords[0];
  } else {
     isRecursive = true;
  }
}
kwdPath = curKwd.OrganizationalItem.Title + "/" + kwdPath;
```

Comment: depending on your version of .Net (3.5+) you could use Linq:
String.Join("/", myKeywordField.Value.ParentKeywords.Select(kw => kw.Title).ToArray());

Comment: One keyword is associated as Metadata of a component. I have Component object and Component.Metadata["keyword_value"] returns XMLElement. In this way i am not able to retrieve  "KeywordField" object. Could you please provide solution for this?

Comment: It will be same as how you read the Content fields from Component. This gives Metadata fields `ItemFields metaFields = new ItemFields(component.Metadata, component.MetadataSchema);`

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can try and play with one of the following:

- keyword.ParentKeywords recursively to create the path you are looking for.
- OrganizationalItem oi = keyword.OrganizationalItem; // to get all the organizational items
- keyword.OwningRepository

Hope that helps!

Comment: Could you please provide some code snippet to how to get Keyword object from value " Keyword 11" ?

Comment: in your TBB: `KeywordField kwdField = (KeywordField)metaFields["kwdField"];` and `kwdField.Value` or `Values` if it is multiple.